# python kivy i don't see just an empty window

Tags: python, kivy

I made my first kivy program. When I run this app, then it appears empty window.

This is the whole program.

Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty

class Myfirstwidget(BoxLayout):

    def text(self, val):
        print('text input text is: {txt}'.format(txt=val))



class MainAPP(App):
    def build(self):
        return Myfirstwidget()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainAPP().run()
```

Kivy code `myfirstwidget.kv` :

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

<Myfirstwidget>:
    Button:
        on_press: self.text(txt_inpt.text)
    TextInput:
        id: txt_inpt
```

Answer (score 2):

Change name of the kv file to `main.kv`.

Its name must be like the name of the App class, but lower case, and without 'app'. More info here [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your kv file.

When you do

```
Button:
        on_press: self.text(txt_inpt.text)
```

you are doing it to the button, not to the MyFirstWidget instance

Instead, you have to do:

```
Button:
    on_press:root.text(txt_inpt.text)
```

That should work